# Show that when $\theta \rightarrow\infty, C(u_1, u_2) \rightarrow \min\{u1, u2\}$, where $C(u_1,u_2)$ is Frank's copula

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I was told that this could be solved only using limits. However, I don't understand how a limit could converge to the function $\min\{u_1,u_2\}$. Also, I can't get any coherent result from taking the limit.

Comment: I don't understand "this could only be solved using limits". As opposed to what? It's a limit... More importantly, you should probably write down Frank's copula.

Answer (score 0):

Looking it up on Wikipedia, Frank's Copula is $$ C(u,v) = -\frac{1}{\theta}\log\left(1 + \frac{(e^{-\theta u}-1)(e^{-\theta v}-1)}{e^{-\theta}-1}\right)$$ (do please learn Mathjax and type the formula so the question is self-contained in the future).

Say $u < v.$ Then we can write what's inside the log as $$ \frac{e^{-\theta}-1 +(e^{-\theta u}-1)(e^{-\theta v}-1) }{e^{-\theta}-1} =\frac{e^{-\theta u}+e^{-\theta v} -e^{-\theta}-e^{-\theta(u+v)}}{1-e^{-\theta}} \\= e^{-\theta u}\frac{1+e^{-(v-u)\theta}-e^{-(1-u)\theta} + e^{-\theta v}}{1-e^{-\theta}}$$ so we have $$ C(u,v) = u -\frac{1}{\theta}\log\left(\frac{1+e^{-(v-u)\theta}-e^{-(1-u)\theta} + e^{-\theta v}}{1-e^{-\theta}}\right).$$ Since $u < v$ and $u < 1$ and $v>0,$ when we take the limit as $\theta\to \infty$ of what's inside the log above, it goes to one. So the limit of that term goes to zero and we're left with $u = \min(u,v).$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, next time I will put the formula inside the question. And what I meant by "this could be solved only using limits" was that I was told it could be solved using limits directly on the Copula's formula instead of what I've found which was applying the limit to the formula for the relation between Kendall's tau and the parameter theta for the copula to show that Kendall's tau goes to 1, implying that you arrive at the comonotonic copula.

Sorry I wasn't that clear when I first posted the question.